# Syntax to for phrase match whilst excluding domains for search results

Tags: google-search

I'm trying to search Google for:

`"Alpha Beta" + "Charlie Delta" -excluding(pinterest.com), -excluding(facebook.com)`

What I'm trying to achieve here is to find results that contain the phrase `"Alpha Beta"` and separately the phrase `"Charlie Delta"`, and to exclude want results from `pinterest.com` and `facebook.com`.

What would the correct syntax for that be?

Answer (score 1):

- correct syntax would be:

```
"alpha beta" "charlie delta" -site:https://www.facebook.com/ -site:https://www.pinterest.com
```